# Blender doesn't open .obj model with textures

Tags: 3d, textures, blender, 3d-reconstruction, autodesk

I have a model in .obj format made by Autodesk Recap 360. It has textures and .mtl file. I can open this model in MeshLab with textures, but not in Blender.

This is how it looks when selected "Textured":

[image]

and this is how it looks when selected "Rendered" in Blender:

[image]

This is the link on the model, you can download it:

**[My model](https://sketchfab.com/models/80294e0a79d0400d93a42f460520759b)**

Thanks in advance for any help.